# click and hover function in a element in jquery

Tags: jquery, css

i have a navigation bar that expands on hover and reduces on mouse out. i want to insert a click function to the navbar, after clicking the navbar will not reduce. how to do it.
presently my code is

```
$(".nav_list li").css('display','none');
    $("#navbar").hover(function(){
        $("#navbar_inner").css({"width":"972px","margin-left":"0px"});
        $(".nav_list li").delay(800).fadeIn(500);
        },
        function(){
            $(".nav_list li").stop(true,true);
            $(".nav_list li").fadeOut(001);
            $("#navbar_inner").css({"width":"70px","margin-left":"451px"});
    });
```

how do i implement the desired result upon my present code

Comment: did you mean on click hover effect will not occur ?

Comment: try `$('#navbar').on('click', function(){ $(this).unbind('hover'); });`

Comment: thanks man working perfectly. what if i want to activate hover function again after the second click

Comment: @TusharGupta reply plz

Comment: I have posted the answer kindly check .

Comment: did it work for you ? have you tested ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".nav_list li").css('display', 'none');

function handler1() {
    $(this).off('hover').one("click", handler2);
}

function handler2() {
    $(this).on('hover').one("click", handler1);
}
$("#navbar").one("click", handler1);
```

Updated after OP's comment

```
$(".nav_list li").css('display', 'none');

function animate() {
    $("#navbar_inner").css({
        "width": "972px",
            "margin-left": "0px"
    });
    $(".nav_list li").delay(800).fadeIn(500);
}

function animate_off() {
    $(".nav_list li").stop(true, true);
    $(".nav_list li").fadeOut(1);
    $("#navbar_inner").css({
        "width": "70px",
            "margin-left": "451px"
    });
}

function handler1() {
    $(this).off('hover').one("click", handler2);
}

function handler2() {
    $(this).on('hover', function () {
        animate();, animate_off();
    }).one("click", handler1);
}
$("#navbar").one("click", handler1);
```

Comment: the navbar is not reducing after once i click on it. how about activate hover function again when i click outside navbar

Answer (score 0):

Yes possible.  You can do it using **[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) event  click handler attachment**

```
$('#navbar').on('click', function(){
 //ToDos
 $(this).unbind('hover');  //Incase if you want to stop hovering
});
```

I would suggest you to use **`.on()`** and **`.off()`** event handler attachment.

```
isHover = true; // Bool variable to hover or not

$("#navbar").on('hover', animation);    

$('#navbar').on('click', function () {
    if (isHover) {
        $(this).off('hover');
        isHover = false;
    } else {
        $(this).on('hover', animation);
        isHover = true;
    }
});

function animation() {
    $("#navbar_inner").css({
        "width": "972px",
        "margin-left": "0px"
    });
    $(".nav_list li").delay(800).fadeIn(500);
}
```

Comment: the navbar is not reducing after once i click on it. how about activate hover function again when i click outside navbar

Comment: @user2682742 Couldn't get you.  I have used it like toggle.  Can you be specific.  If possible post a fiddle.

Comment: toggle function is not working. once i click on the navbar its not reducing in size after i click again. i want to reduce it in size and activate hover function on it again after i click anywhere away from navabr

Comment: @user2682742 can you add your specific html attributes?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#navbar').on('click', function(){
$("#navbar_inner").css({"width":"972px","margin-left":"0px"});
});
```